# Django imeplement custom model field without migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

I'm trying to implement custom field in my model following the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-model-fields/), My model is as follow:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    uid = models.CharField(
        "uid", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        "Phone number", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(
        "Nickname", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    eth_address = models.CharField("Eth address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # deleted
    class eth_address_decrypted(models.Field):
        description = 'eth_address_decrypted'

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return decrypt_string(self.eth_address)


    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    pass
```

I have a `eth_address` field that it's value are encrypted, i need to display the decrypted value on the frontend, so i wrote custom field model as the docs and call it on my front end through query:

> User.objects.get(eth_address_decrypted=value)

But it returning the following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'eth_address_decrypted' into field. Choices are: created, date_joined, email, eth_address,
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Is there a way i can call `user.eth_address_decrypted` on object as a custom field or function without migrating it ? (because eth_address_decrypted just a convert from existed eth_adress)

Comment: This is not a field (since that should at least be a field *instance*. Hence the error makes sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how should i approach this ? since i don't want to migrate a new field i would like to just show the decrypted data when i call `user. eth_address_decrypted` on that object

Comment: You can just define a regular python class property in your model where you return decrypted data. But you wont be able to make query with that as you are trying to do.